# Bad Company 2 Vietnam compatibility

Tags: ps3, battlefield-bad-company-2, battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam

A friend of mine bought the Vietnam expansion in the Playstation Store and tried to share with me. I downloaded the expansion with the account he provided, but it didn't work, the option to play Vietnam didn't show on my game's menu. My Bad Company 2 copy is from Hong Kong, and he said it might be because the account he used to buy his Vietnam expansion was from the UK. If I buy the expansion myself with my US account, will it work for my copy of the game? Is there a way to know beforehand if it will work?

Answer (score 1):

BC2 Vietnam expansion pack is physically just the activation code (similar to CD-key) to enable it. Obviously it can be used only once for one account only.

Comment: So, will it work if I buy it, regardless of which account I use or the region my copy was bought in?

Comment: Well, I don't know how about PSN version, in case of PC it's all just sold by EA Store and linked to EA user account.